# Confidence and prediction intervals for log-log transformed data

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

I am making S-N curves and I have trouble.

Assume I have a formula
$S=f(2N)^b,$ where $f$ and $b$ are constants for which I want to calculate PI and CI, $2N$ is a dependent variable, $S$ is independent.
Measured data is in log log distribution.

Standard procedure is to use linear regression in form Y=b0*X+b1 so after log log transformation,

$$\log(2N)=\frac{1}{b}\log(S)-\frac{\log(f)}{b} ,$$

where $ Y=\log(2N),$ $X=\log(S),$ $b_0=1/b,$ and $b_1=-(1/b) \log(f).$

From linear regression formulas I can calculate confidence and prediction intervals for $b_0$ and $b_1.$
However, I want to calculate CI and PI for the original $f$ and $b$ values $(b=1/b_0,$ $f=10^{-b_0/b_1}.$
I am thinking that calculating $b=1/(b_0\pm \operatorname{error})$ and $f=10^{-(b_0\pm  \operatorname{error})/(b_1\pm  \operatorname{error})}$ is not the right way.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: parameters in the frequentist approach are fixed thus prediction intervals are not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks, but the slope and Y intercept do have some errors so PI and CI are helpful I think.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. CI and PI of transformed data is a genuine question

Comment: Welcome to CV, Vajo.  Could you please explain what a *prediction interval* for a *parameter* like $b_0$ or $b_1$ might be?  Your description implies these parameters are fixed numbers, not random variables, and the usual meaning of a prediction interval does not seem to apply.